# "overflow: hidden" on "body" produces glitchy scrollbar with USB mouse

Tags: css, google-chrome, scrollbar, overflow, mouse

I'm building a web application and testing with Google Chrome. I have a sidebar element where, if I hover over that element, I want to disable scrolling for the `body` element.

I achieved this by setting `overflow: hidden` on the `body` tag using CSS whenever a user hovers over the sidebar. I tested this on a browser without a USB mouse plugged in, and it worked great:

**Sidebar Closed** (`body` scrollbar visible)

[image]

**Sidebar Open - Bad** (`body` scrollbar still visible, producing an ugly overlap)

[image]

**Sidebar Open - Good** (my fix: hiding `body` scrollbar, so that sidebar scrollbar displays alone)

[image]

This works because Google Chrome doesn't render scrollbars as actual elements (that have widths). However, when I plug in my USB mouse, the scrollbars now do have widths. And thus, when I move my mouse from outside the scrollbar to inside the scrollbar, the width suddenly changes:

**Before Hover** (`body` scrollbar visible)

[image]

**After Hover - Bad**  (`body` scrollbar hidden, suddenly decreasing the width of the whole sidebar)

[image]

This produces a really ugly and glitchy visual effect, where the widths of elements change when you hover over them. I've looked everywhere for a solution to this... any help would be much appreciated! Thanks so much!

Comment: Please can you post a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), it will help us be able to assist you with your problem.

Answer (score 8):

If you are on a mac, chances are your OS is adding the scroll bar when you plug in the mouse, a scroll bar that will override most CSS selectors.

There is not a way to override this with CSS that I am aware of. If you change your system preferences you will find your website behaving the way you intended.

System Preferences -> General -> Show Scroll Bars -> Change from [ALWAYS] to [WHEN SCROLLING]

[image: show scroll bar settings]

Answer (score 3):

```
.MY_CSS_CLASS::-webkit-scrollbar {
    width: 0px;
    height: 0px;
    background: transparent;
}
```

This fixed my issue with ugly scrollbar being displayed when mouse is connected.

Answer (score 2):

Specifying `width` to the body element will keep content width constant.

Here is the working example: https://jsfiddle.net/fuhacLtn/2/

Comment: your answered helped me understanding something I was looking for, upvoted for that! would you tell m what exactly is document.body.style.overflow = 'auto'; used for?

Comment: `overflow` displays scroll bars when the content exceeds element's dimension. overflow: auto will display horizontal scroll bar if content exceeds the container's width and vertical scroll bar if height exceeds.
The statement `document.body.style.overflow = 'auto'` will assign overflow to `body` element.
Reference: http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_pos_overflow.asp

Answer (score 1):

First, you should pay attention to the **rendering with other browsers** and with chrome windows. As you know, the *windows* scroll bar is clearly not the same and is not *rendered* in the same way. You might have surprises with this.

Otherwise you maybe should pay attention to [jQuery custom content scroller](http://manos.malihu.gr/jquery-custom-content-scroller/#plugin-data-contentTouchScroll) plugins.

This could actually helps you a bit more to **control** the *scroll* & the `overflow` and **customize** the *scroll bar* depending on the render you would like to give to it.

Good Luck'